# Programmatic equivalent for Spring Boot TLS keystore config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, dynamic

I have the following lines in my `application.yml`:

```
server.ssl:
  key-store: classpath:keystore/keystore.p12
  key-store-password: password
  key-store-type: PKCS12
```

The [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl) also gives a similar example, and states:

> SSL can be configured declaratively by setting the various `server.ssl.*` properties, typically in `application.properties` or `application.yml`.

However, I want to determine the keystore dynamically.

How do I write this programmatically in the application code, rather than via the config files?